# Get Text From Specific Textboxes From External Application - Visual Basic .Net

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, external-application

I can get text from external application text box but now I want to get text from my desired text box from external application.
My English is not so good that's why see Image Below.

[image]

The Below Code Return The First Text Box Value Only.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class Form1

Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, _
ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, _
                                 ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, _
                                 ByVal lclassName As String, _
                                 ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Declare Auto Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Find the running notepad window
    Dim Hwnd As IntPtr = FindWindow(Nothing, TextBox1.Text)

    'Alloc memory for the buffer that recieves the text
    Dim Handle As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100)

    'send WM_GWTTEXT message to the notepad window
    Dim NumText As Integer = SendMessage(Hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, 50, Handle)

    'copy the characters from the unmanaged memory to a managed string
    Dim Text As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Handle)

    'Display the string using a label
    Label1.Text = Text

    'Find the Edit control of the Running Notepad
    Dim ChildHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", Nothing)

    'Alloc memory for the buffer that recieves the text
    Dim Hndl As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200)

    'Send The WM_GETTEXT Message
    NumText = SendMessage(ChildHandle, WM_GETTEXT, 200, Hndl)

    'copy the characters from the unmanaged memory to a managed string
    Text = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl)

    'Display the string using a label
    Label2.Text = Text


End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: On a side note - you should make sure you call [Marshal.FreeHGlobal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal.aspx) with your `Handle` and `Hndl` variables to free the memory you've allocated. This memory isn't allocated using standard .NET mechanisms, so .NET's garbage collection won't clean it up for you.

Comment: You may want to check this post: [Extract all child windows of window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345267/extract-all-child-windows-of-window/14408950#14408950).
There I include a sample VB.NET program that can detect and read the text (among other things) of every single window.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to loop through children of the main window (External Application) and get their properties.
You'll use the following:

```
<DllImport("User32.dll")> _
    Public Function EnumChildWindows _
        (ByVal WindowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal Callback As EnumWindowProcess, _
        ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Delegate Function EnumWindowProcess(ByVal Handle As IntPtr, ByVal Parameter As IntPtr) As Boolean

Public Function GetChildWindows(ByVal ParentHandle As IntPtr) As IntPtr()
    Dim ChildrenList As New List(Of IntPtr)
    Dim ListHandle As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(ChildrenList)
    Try
        EnumChildWindows(ParentHandle, AddressOf EnumWindow, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(ListHandle))
    Finally
        If ListHandle.IsAllocated Then ListHandle.Free()
    End Try
    Return ChildrenList.ToArray
End Function
```

For for details, check this [How can I get properties of controls contained in a popup message box using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719147/how-can-i-get-properties-of-controls-contained-in-a-popup-message-box-using-vb-n/24723000?noredirect=1#comment38358369_24723000)

Answer (score 0):

'    try this on excel vbe

```
External_application_handle=findwindow(vbNullString,"External_application")
textbox_1_handle=findwindowex(External_application_handle,0&,"Edit",vbNullString)
next_handle=textbox_1_handle
textbox_2_handle=findwindowex(External_application_handle,next_handle,"Edit",vbNullString")
Length = SendMessage(textbox_2_handle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0,0)
buffer$=space(Length)
call sendmessage(textbox_2_handle,Length+1,buffer$)
msgbox buffer
```

Comment: Please provide context to your answer, only code may solve the problem but probably doesn'T help the OP to udnerstand what he did wrong.