# How to restrict external application accessing my windows application

Tags: vb6

We have a windows application created using Visual Basic 6.0.

An external application accesses the controls and data present in the forms (screens) of our VB application and prompts validation messages to the user. We assume that the external application is using the 'FindWindow', 'FindWindowEx' API functions present in the user32.dll to access our application using the logic as explained in the following link.

[Get Text From Specific Textboxes From External Application - Visual Basic .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090479/get-text-from-specific-textboxes-from-external-application-visual-basic-net)

Is it possible to restrict the external applications from accessing the controls and data present in the forms (screens) of our VB application?  Is there any method to restrict this anonymous access?

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks,
Sujatha.

Comment: Hard to stop this in a way that can't be circumvented. Can you give us more details? Who created this external application - an over-confident legitimate user in another department, a Russian spy, or who? How bad a problem is it?

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways to fend off hijackers is to substitute controls from [How To Install the Microsoft Windowless Controls for VB6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189950) for many of the intrinsic controls.

This simple step thwarts a lot of the parasites.

Answer (score 1):

Your program hands the text over. The VB6 forms package is doing it for you. Subclass the window and kill the GetText message. See https://www.google.com.au/search?q=vb6+subclass+form.